# Livy not working for PySpark and Spark in Hortonworks

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I started a REST spark session via livy as shown:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"kind": "spark"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/sessions

{
"from": 0,
"sessions": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "kind": "spark",
        "log": [
            "16/07/18 05:05:44 INFO ScalatraListener: The cycle class name from the config: com.cloudera.livy.repl.ScalatraBootstrap",
            "16/07/18 05:05:44 INFO ScalatraListener: Initializing life cycle class: ScalatraBootstrap"
        ],
        "proxyUser": null,
        "state": "starting"
    }
],
"total": 1
}
```

However I'm using Hortonworks instead of Cloudera and I have configured the settings according to http://hortonworks.com/apache/zeppelin/#section_3:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark-client
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_60
export PATH=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:$PATH
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
export LIVY_SERVER_JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2g"
```

I ended up with this error:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "sessions": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "kind": "spark",
            "log": [
                "\tat com.cloudera.livy.repl.scalaRepl.SparkInterpreter.execute(SparkInterpreter.scala:111)",
                "\tat com.cloudera.livy.repl.Session.com$cloudera$livy$repl$Session$$executeCode(Session.scala:98)",
                "\tat com.cloudera.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$3.apply(Session.scala:73)",
                "\tat com.cloudera.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$3.apply(Session.scala:73)",
                "\tat scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)",
                "\tat scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)",
                "\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)",
                "\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)",
                "\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)",
                "16/07/18 05:25:13 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down."
            ],
            "proxyUser": null,
            "state": "error"
        }
    ],
    "total": 1
}
```

I suspect that my pyspark and spark jobs are not working as they keep pointing to Cloudera's classes instead of Hortonworks.

It may or not be due to the configs as I saw the code in https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/apps/spark/java/bin/livy-repl that the class is defaulted to com.cloudera.hue.livy.repl.Main, but I'm not very familiar with Livy at this point to tell how whether this is the actual bug or not.

How can I make sure that Livy is working with Apache Spark via Hortonworks?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Spark in HDP 2.4 these are the configuration changes I have made

Add

```
spark.master  yarn-cluster
```

in '/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/spark-defaults.conf'

**livy-env.sh**

Add these entries

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark-client   
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/bin/    
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf    
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=$SPARK_HOME/conf    
export LIVY_LOG_DIR=/jobserver-livy/logs    
export LIVY_PID_DIR=/jobserver-livy    
export LIVY_MAX_LOG_FILES=10    
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/bin
```

**livy.conf**

Add this entry at the end of the file

```
livy.rsc.rpc.server.address=<loop back ip address>
```